# Modal not closed when update is done in CRUD with php ajax&jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Why is this not working, because of a problem in Bootstrap or ajax?

This is my modal update:

```
<div class="container">
                  <!-- Modal update -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModals<?php echo $row->id ;?>" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="user">Username:</label>
                              <input type="user" class="form-control" id="users<?php echo $row->id ;?>" value="<?php echo $row->username ;?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="password">Password:</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwords<?php echo $row->id ;?>" value="<?php echo $row->password ;?>">
                            </div>
                            <button onclick='update("<?= $row->id ?>")' type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
                          </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

And this is my ajax:

```
 function update(id){
var users = $("#users"+id).val();
var passwords = $("#passwords"+id).val();

$.ajax({
  dataType:'html',
  url:"update.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:"users="+users+"&passwords="+passwords+"&id="+id,
}).done(function(data){
  load();
  $('back-drop').remove();
});
```

}

Why is this not working when I submit the change, the modal form is not closed completely like this:

[image]

Comment: Truy once with $('myModals'+id).modal('close ');

Comment: You have a typo there. `$('myModals'+id).modal('hide')` should be `$('#myModals'+id).modal('hide')`. You forgot the hash `#` in the selector.

Comment: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" (or variants of such) to the title of your questions; instead either accept the answer which helped to solve your problem or, if you solved it yourself, write your own answer detailing your solution and accept your own answer (though there is a delay of two days before you can accept your own answer), that way the system knows it's solved, and presents it visually as such. If you solved your problem using information not present in the question then please post the answer *and* [edit] the question to present all relevant (though "*[mcve]*") code and information.

Comment: ok thanks @DavidThomas .

Answer (score 1):

Please recheck your selector in the **hide()** syntax. You've forgotten the # in front.

Change this:

```
$('myModals'+id).modal('hide');
```

To this:

```
$('#myModals'+id).modal('hide');
```

For checking such issues, you should use Google Chrome and press CTRL + Shift + J. The possible syntax errors will be shown in the console.